# Unable to locate block in the layout files

Tags: magento2, layout, bundled-product

I need to change some layouts on the product detail page.
So I tried to locate some blocks in the layout files.

Using the template path hints fo example I know about a block with the template 
`catalog/product/view/customize.phtml`

But searching the project with PHP Storm for the term `customize.phtml` just returns cache files.
For example in the cache there's this line:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="customize.button" as="customize_button" template="Magento_Bundle::catalog/product/view/customize.phtml" after="product.info.price"/>
```

But i thought there had to be be a layout xml adding this block somewhere.
Just not able to find it using the PHP Storm Search.

Where is this being added to the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you will find the entry here:

vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="customize.button" as="customize_button" template="Magento_Bundle::catalog/product/view/customize.phtml" after="product.info.price" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 xml files where customize.phtml is involved:

```
vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_index_configure_type_bundle.xml
vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml
```

maybe the vendor folder is outside your phpstorm project

Comment: indeed it is, as I just found out just moments before reading this